# Multithread program execution time?

Tags: c, multithreading, time

I wrote a C multi-threaded program, if I use clock() function or time function of shell bash, it gives a time that seems the time of on thread * number of threads, so if the program execute in 1 second it gives 6 seconds using 6 threads. But with a long time it's not a simple division anymore, so I want to know if there is a function that measures the real execution time and not the sum of all threads time

Comment: `time` gives both CPU time and wall-clock time. Which number are you asking about? You can have a situation where 10 seconds of wall-clock time elapses but a few minutes of CPU time has been consumed on systems with large numbers of threads.

Comment: You could call `gettimeofday()` once before the start of the computation and again just after you've `join()`'d all the threads, and then subtract the two timestamps.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner yes, i did this with clock() and i got the result i wrote above, with gettimeofday i think it's the same, but now i try

Comment: @JeremyFriesner POSIX has obsoleted `gettimeofday()`. Should use `clock_gettime()` in new code. (Which, on linux at least, has a clock that measures per-thread CPU time, and one for total process time)

Comment: @Shawn very good function, it works